# how to cast a reference to int8_t to a reference to uint8_t?

Tags: c++, reference, casting

i try to cast a reference of int8_t to a reference of uint8_t.

i have the following code:

```c
inline mtype& operator&(mtype& mt, uint8_t& va) {
  // do something
  // ...

  return mt;
}

inline mtype& operator&(mtype& mt, int8_t& va) {
  // do the same but signed
  // ...

  return mt;
}
```

since both overloads doing the same, i want to [dry](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%E2%80%99t_repeat_yourself) (or better drm), so i would like to call the first operator with `casted va`. but how do i do that? this won't work.

```
inline mtype& operator&(mtype& mt, int8_t& va) {
  return mt& static_cast<uint8_t>(va); //  error: no match for 'operator&' in 'mt & (uint8_t)va'
}
```

how do i do that right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to *reinterpret* what the data is.

```
inline mtype& operator&(mtype& mt, int8_t& va) {
  return mt& reinterpret_cast<uint8_t&>(va);
}
```

Be careful though.  Depending on what "do the same but signed" means, you may not be doing The Right Thing by calling the same function and assuming the data is always *unsigned*.

If your code *is* doing work that has unique signed/unsigned logic (despite the code looking the same) you'll want to use a template function to generate the correct type-specific logic.

```
template< Typename T >
mtype& do_the_work( mtype& mt, T& va )
{
  // do something

  // (Here's an example of code that LOOKS the same, but doesn't DO the same)
  va = va >> 1;
}

inline mtype& operator&(mtype& mt, uint8_t& va) {
  return do_the_work( mt, va );
}

inline mtype& operator&(mtype& mt, int8_t& va) {
  return do_the_work( mt, va );
}
```

Comment: You should probably pedantically observe that on a hypothetical system where these types are not just typedef to `char` types, the `reinterpret_cast` would violate the strict alias rules.

Answer (score 1):

```
inline mtype& operator&(mtype& mt, int8_t& va) {
  return mt & reinterpret_cast<uint8_t&>(va);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error you get is because the cast results in a value not a reference.

You should use:

```
reinterpret_cast<uint8_t&>(va)
```

Comment: @MikeSeymour Right, my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're casting to a non-const value but your functions expect non-const references.

Almost certainly what you *really* want is for the operators to accept the second parameter by value (and if your `operator&` really does mutate its right hand operator you need to rethink your operator):

```
inline mtype& operator&(mtype& mt, uint8_t va) {
  // do something
  // ...

  return mt;
}

inline mtype& operator&(mtype& mt, int8_t va) {
  return mt& static_cast<uint8_t>(va); //  error: no match for 'operator&' in 'so & (uint8_t)va'
}
```